# Definition of a random variable $\mathrm{Var}(X)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance

So $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{E}((X-\mu)^2)$, but how can you subtract a function $(X)$ by a value ($\mu)$? And does it make sense to square a function?

Comment: First of all, we perform basic operations on functions (such as adding things and squaring them) all the time.  Second X is not a function it is a random variable.

Comment: The only unusual bit of notation is that we suppress the dependence on the sampling variable $\omega$ when we talk about random variables. If you make everything explicit by writing $Y(\omega)=(X(\omega)-\mu)^2$, everything is now standard function notation.

Comment: @DougM In the usual formalism, random variables are functions.

Comment: Note that the expected value is involved. Therefore all expressions in the brackets become constants. $E(X^2-2X\mu+\mu)=E(X^2)-2\mu E(X)+\mu^2=E(X^2)-\mu^2=\text{constant 1-constant 2=constant}$

Comment: @DougM Since when are random variables not functions?

Comment: The short answer is that $X$ and $\mu$ are both just real numbers, so you can subtract them. Just like $f(x)-1$ is ok to do since $f(x)$ is a number once $x$ is fixed. Of course $X$ isn't a "fixed" real number, but neither is $f(x)$. Also note that $\mu$ is also a random variable, just not an interesting one.

Comment: @jdods Sorry but $X$ is a function, not a real number, $\mu$ is a real number, and $X-\mu$ is a function because one knows how to define a function by adding a constant to a function.

Comment: @Did, Read my comment carefully.

Comment: @jdods You know, I did that before writing my comment... `The short answer is that X and μ are both just real numbers` No. But you could have written that $X(\omega)$ is "just a real number", this would have been true.

Comment: @Did, It's normal to leave off the $\omega$ even sometimes when one is actually there. I think my example of $f$ makes that clear. The OP may of may not even know what $\Omega$ is, so it may or may not help to mention it. And it is already explained in the answer below. I am providing the OP with a helpful, simple way to come to understanding. The answer is that both $X$ and $\mu$ are numbers and they are both functions.

Comment: @jdods "It's normal to leave off the ω" In general, yes, but certainly not when, as here, the main message to convey to dispel the OP's confusion is that numbers and functions are different objects!

Comment: @Did, I've expanded my comment to an answer in order to dispel any confusion it may cause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very valid question, and one that I didn't really touch until my second time learning undergraduate probability. **I am by no means an expert**; this is merely the intuition I've developed.

$X$ *is* a function. What they don't tell you in undergraduate-level probability is that $$X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$$
is a "random variable," where $\Omega$ is the sample space of events. You're not particularly interested in the function itself, but values that $\Omega$ map to - i.e., the *range* of $X$. So technically speaking, it is more correct to write $X(\omega)$ when in undergraduate-level probability, you write $X$.

But this opens up a huge can of worms that, quite frankly, there isn't time to cover in undergraduate-level probability. If we know what $X$ means now, what does $\mu$ actually mean? In the undergraduate sense, you're told some form of 
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}}kf_{X}(k)$$
for $X$ a discrete random variable, but then the following comes to question: what *is* $f_{X}$, anyway?

Well, you're told that $f_{X}(k) = \mathbb{P}(X = k)$. But what does THIS mean now? We have shown now that $X = k$ is problematic, so $X$ should be $X(\omega)$. But what is $\mathbb{P}$?

It turns out that you need a function $$\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \to [0, 1]$$
- $\mathcal{P}$ denoting the power set. Basically, you are assigning **collections of sets** (hence why the domain is the power set) in $\Omega$ numbers in $[0, 1]$. In probability in particular, you're told you can take probabilities of unions of sets, intersections, etc....

It turns out that not every collection of sets in $\Omega$ can work this way (i.e., not every set can be unioned, intersected, etc. to give a set with a probability measure), so you need to choose a collection of sets in $\Omega$ (i.e., a subset of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$) for which this makes sense. Such a collection of sets is called a $\sigma$-algebra (say $\mathcal{B}$) and we call the triplet $(\Omega, \mathcal{B}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space. **So, as Ian has commented**, $$\mathbb{P}: \mathcal{B} \to [0, 1]\text{.}$$- in particular, $\mathbb{P}$ is called a *probability measure*.

Now back to the original story: what I've revealed to you is that the statement $\mathbb{P}(X = k)$ has many things wrong with it. $X$ should be a function, and furthermore, $X=k$ should be a **set**. **BUT**, the range of the values of $X$ are not what actually are used in computing probabilities: NOTICE that the range of $X$ is $\mathbb{R}$ and the domain of $\mathbb{P}$ is $\mathcal{B}$, some collection of subsets of $\Omega$. So indeed, what we need to do is map the range of values of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\Omega$, and THEN apply the probability measure $\mathbb{P}$. So actually,
$$\mathbb{P}(X = k) = \mathbb{P}\left(X^{-1}(\{k\})\right)$$
where $X^{-1}$ is the *inverse image* of $X$ (NOT the inverse). And then you have to make sure that $X^{-1}(\{k\})$ is in a $\sigma$-algebra as well.

Finally, we now know that
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{R}}k \cdot \mathbb{P}\left(X^{-1}(\{k\})\right)\text{.}$$

Note that I haven't even touched continuous random variables. I know virtually none of the theory involved there.

This material, and much more, is covered in a graduate-level treatment of probability with measure theory.

Comment: The only mathematical error you made here is that the domain of $\mathbb{P}$ is not $\Omega$. For discrete measures, one can identify $\mathbb{P}$ with a function whose domain is $\Omega$, namely $p(x)=\mathbb{P}(\{ x \})$. But in general, and in particular for the uniform distribution on an interval, we cannot do this.

Comment: Thank you @Ian; I've made edits.

Comment: Awesome explanation, Clarinetist! One more place to replace $\Omega$ with $\mathcal{B}$ (not to be nit picky), but I don't want to soil your work with my hands by editing it myself!

Comment: Now what you've said is basically correct, in the sense that you say something wrong (namely that the domain is all of $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$) and then correct it in the next paragraph.

Comment: @Ian How are the edits now?

Comment: Your claim of technical error in undergraduate probability makes totally no sense. $\{A\} \cap \{B\} = \varnothing$ for **any distinct objects** $A,B$, regardless of what they are. The notation in common use is actually 'more correct' in this case; because we can treat $A,B$ as subsets of the sample space times density, namely the measure of the volume under the probability density function, at least for continuous random variables. It'd probably be better to just remove your "ETA".

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided is excellent, however I'll offer a little simpler perspective.

Subtraction, "$-$", is what's called a *binary operation* on numbers. The subtraction operation "combines" two numbers and outputs a single number (technicalities and generalities aside).

Subtraction of functions is defined in terms of how subtraction of numbers works. We define a new function $h$ by $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ for all fixed $x$ values, and then we use the notation $f-g$ to represent $h$.

We have to understand what the formula for variance means:
$$
E((X-\mu)^2)= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (x-\mu)^2f_X(x) \ dx\\
$$
where both $x$ and $\mu$ are real numbers, and $f_X(x)$ is the probability function of random variable $X$ (evaluated at $x$, of course). So the actual subtraction only happens between numbers.

Similarly, only numbers are being squared.